# Tkinter: Draw rectangle using a mouse, and crop a photo in the shape of that rectangle

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

I found this code online, and I changed it for my benefit, so it creates a rectangle and then it crops the photo in the shape of this rectangle. But, I've been facing a problem for a very long time: when the mouse is released, I can't use the image that I created and return it and use it in a variable.  I think it's the section of `on_button_release`.

Basically, I would like to take a photo, then allow the user to draw a rectangle on the screen, crop this certain image in the rectangle shape and use it after wise in a variable as a PIL image.

Here's some code I found online after I changed it for my benefit:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *


class ExampleApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, file_path):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
        self.file_path = file_path

        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(self,  cursor="cross")

        self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,stick=N+S)
        self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

        self.rect = None

        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None


        self.im = PIL.Image.open(self.file_path)
        self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.wazil,self.lard))
        self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)


    def on_button_press(self,event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.start_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        if not self.rect:
            self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, outline='red')

    def on_move_press(self,event):
        curX = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        curY = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        w, h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
        if event.x > 0.9*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, 'units')
        elif event.x < 0.1*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, 'units')
        if event.y > 0.9*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
        elif event.y < 0.1*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)
        self.im2 = self.im.crop((self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY))
        self.tk_im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im2)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im2)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = 'images.jpg'
    root=Tk()
    app = ExampleApp(root, file_path = file_path)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Event handlers are called by `tkinter` when the event they're bound to occurs and don't return any values— so asking how to "return it and use it in a variable" doesn't make sense. About all you can do in `on_button_press()` is store data in attributes of the `ExampleApp` using `self.` or store it in external global variables.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my code, I want to use this photo, that the user cropped, outside the class, so how can I stop the event and use it?

Comment: You can't "stop" an event as they correspond to user input that has already happened that the program is now reacting to by calling one of your bound event handler functions. In the class' `on_button_release()` event-handling method you could call `self.quit()` to terminate the GUI  and make the call to `root.mainloop()` at the end return — so you'll need to add code following that statement to make use of the last cropped image that was stored in `app.im2`.

Comment: Great, that worked, thanks a lot, you are the best!